# Replace path in specific line number of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have a file which contain :

```
 Source defaults file; edit that file to configure this script.
 
 AUTOSTART="all"
 
 STATUSREFRESH=10
 
 OMIT_SENDSIGS=0
 
 if test -e /etc/default/openvpn ; then
 
   . /etc/default/openvpn
 
 fi
```

i want to change the path `/etc/default/openvpn` in line 5 to `/mnt/data/default/openvpn`
the same thing about line 6.
I couldn't using `sed -i '5s/etc/default...'` ,
and with awk i can't replace the result in the file.

any one have a idea please ?

Thank you.

commands tried :

```
var1='/etc/default/openvpn'

var2='/mnt/data/default/openvpn'

sed -i '5s/'$var'/'$var2'/' files.txt

sed -i '5s/etc/default/openvpn/mnt/data/default/openvpn/' files.txt

sed -i '5s/'/etc/default/openvpn'/'/mnt/data/default/openvpn'/g' files.txt

awk 'NR==5 { sub("/etc/default/openvpn", "/etc/default/openvpn", $0); print }' files.txt
```

with awk, i can't save changes in the file

Comment: "i couldn't using sed -i '5s/etc/default...'"  Why not? Did you try it and it didn't work? Edit the question to show us what you tried and maybe we can help fix it.

Comment: okey, post modified  thanks

Comment: Why only in lines 5 and 6?  That is extremely fragile.  It sounds like you simply want to replace the path everywhere.  Note that this sort of thing is a *lot* easier if you don't repeat yourself (DRY); specify the path in only one location in the file by assigning it to a variable and use the variable as needed.

Comment: Note that with `sed -i`, you can't replace the content of the file either.  It creates a new file for you and renames it to have the name of the original file.

Comment: @Guillaume Pursell
the file that i would modify is /etc/init.d/openvpn : you can check in your linux 
i want to change the path of line 37 and 38 of this file which is the same lines in my file 5 and 6 
so i took this part just to do tests

Comment: @WilliamPursell

no, with sed i can replace string by string in the same file without creatin another file, 
but in this case i cant change path because it's not coonsider as string they have '/' between word

Comment: @corol You are mistaken.  `sed -i` creates a new file and then renames it.  Check the inodes of the file before and after you run `sed`.  It's a different file.  This is a subtlety that will eventually burn you badly.  Avoid `sed -i` like the plague.  Or, at least, make sure you truly understand what it is doing and why it is dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here would be the delimiter in use as it will conflict with `sed`'s default delimiter.

To resolve this, you can change the delimiter in use to any other character that does not appear in your data or escaping the default delimiter `\/`.

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak 's|/etc/default/openvpn|/mnt/data/default/openvpn|' input_file
$ cat input_file


    Source defaults file; edit that file to configure this script.

    AUTOSTART=all

    STATUSREFRESH=10

    OMIT_SENDSIGS=0

    if test -e /mnt/data/default/openvpn ; then

    . /mnt/data/default/openvpn

    fi
```

Comment: That's the idea, 
Thanks a lot

Comment: in my case i use : sed -i.bak '5s|/etc/default/openvpn|/mnt/data/default/openvpn|' files.txt 
to modify  line 5, that's work thank you